# XML Parsing and showing the result in a list view

Tags: android, xml-parsing, listactivity

I am using the following code by the Android-people-XMLParsing example for parsing XML file and it is working perfectly fine..

but it retrieve the data in TextView i want  to put this data in a ListView..

I tried by creating CustomAdapter and by changing the Activity into the ListActivity..but nothing works..i can see only a blank screen..Can anyone help me to do this...

Thanks!!

```
     package com.androidpeople.xml.parsing;

     import java.net.URL;
     import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
     import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
     import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
     import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.graphics.Color;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.widget.LinearLayout;
     import android.widget.TextView;

    public class XMLParsingExample extends Activity {

/** Create Object For markerList Class */
mymarkers markerList =null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /** Create a new layout to display the view */
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(1);



    /** Create a new textview array to display the results */
    TextView name[];
    TextView address[];
    TextView city[];
    try {

        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL("xxxxxxxxx");

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

    /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
    markerList = MyXMLHandler.markerList;

    /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */


    name = new TextView[markerList.getName().size()];
    address = new TextView[markerList.getaddress().size()];
    city = new TextView[markerList.getCity().size()];
    /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
    for (int i = 0; i < markerList.getName().size(); i++) {
        name[i] = new TextView(this);
        name[i].setText("Name = "+markerList.getName().get(i));

        address[i] = new TextView(this);
        address[i].setText("address = "+markerList.getaddress().get(i));

        city[i] = new TextView(this);  
        city[i].setText("city = "+markerList.getCity().get(i));
        System.out.println("count33..."+markerList.getCity().size());
        city[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        layout.addView(name[i]);
        layout.addView(address[i]);
        layout.addView(city[i]);

        //layout.addView(border[i]);
    }

    /** Set the layout view to display */
    setContentView(layout);

}
}
```

Comment: I think you need to learn the ListView and custom adpater for ListView first. Then it is easy for you to implement the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered a very similar question few days back that you might want to check. You could check the question [Android: Sax parsing to a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136593/android-sax-parsing-to-a-listview/7136753#7136753) and check the accepted answer. Follow the instruction until getView() part and you should be ok.

In summary here is what you need to do:

- Use DOM instead of SAX, it's simpler and perfect for ListView
- Implement an Adapter that extends BaseAdapter passing the root element to this adapter
- Implement getView in the adapter to add the TextView that you want

Again I've laid out the steps in the [Android: Sax parsing to a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136593/android-sax-parsing-to-a-listview/7136753#7136753). Let me know if you have any further questions